# error:Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: react-redux

Thanks for everyone stop here whether you inspire me or not.In App.js,there is error message:`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`
This is very classic `todolist` project in reduxjs official document,but I reshape it with react and react-redux hooks.
Tree view down:

[image]

Index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Addtodo from "./components/Addtodo";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Todolist from "./components/Todolist";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Addtodo />
      <Todolist />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

actions.js

```
let nextTodoId = 0;
const addtodo = (text) => {
  return {
    type: "ADD_TODO",
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text: text
  };
};
const toggletodo = (id) => {
  return { type: "TOGGLE_TODO", id: id };
};

const setfilter = (filter) => {
  return {
    type: "SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER",
    filter: filter
  };
};
const todoActions = { addtodo, toggletodo };
const filterActions = { setfilter };
const allActions = {
  todoActions,
  filterActions
};
export default allActions;
```

reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
const todo = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return { id: action.id, text: action.text, completed: false };
    case "TOGGLE_TODO":
      if (state.id === action.id)
        return { ...state, completed: !state.completed };
      else return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return [...state, todo(undefined, action)];
    case "TOGGLE_TODO":
      return state.map((s) => todo(s, action));
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const visibilityFilter = (state = "ALL", action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER":
      if (state !== action.filter) return action.filter;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ todos, visibilityFilter });
export default rootReducer;
```

Addtodo.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import allActions from "../actions";


const Addtodo=() => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return(
    <>
    <input
    ref={(node) => {
      this.input = node;
    }}
  /> 
      <button
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch(allActions.todoActions.addtodo(this.input.value));
        this.input.value = "";
      }}
    >
      Add To Do
    </button>
    </>
  );
};
export default Addtodo;
```

Todolist.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import allActions from "../actions";

const getvisibletodos = (todos = [], currentFilter) => {
  switch (currentFilter) {
    case "ALL":
      return todos;
    case "ACTIVE":
      return todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === false);
    case "COMPLETED":
      return todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === true);
  }
};

const Todolist = () => {
  const todos = useSelector((state) =>
    getvisibletodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <li
          key={todo.id}
          style={{ textDecoration: todo.completed ? "line-through" : "none" }}
          onClick={() => dispatch(allActions.todoActions.toggletodo(todo.id))}
        >
          {todo.text}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
export default Todolist;
```

Footer.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import allActions from "../actions";

const Filterlink = ({
  children,
  filter
}) => {
  const active = useSelector(state => state.visibilityFilter ===filter);
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  if (active) {
    return <span>{children}</span>;
  }

  return (
    <a href='#'
       onClick={e => {
         e.preventDefault();
         dispatch(allActions.filterActions.setfilter(filter));
       }}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};
export  const Footer = () => (
  <p>
    Show:
    {' '}
    <FilterLink filter='ALL'>
      All
    </FilterLink>
    {', '}
    <FilterLink filter='ACTIVE'>
      Active
    </FilterLink>
    {', '}
    <FilterLink filter='COMPLETED'>
      Completed
    </FilterLink>
  </p>
);
```

The codesandebox link available:https://codesandbox.io/s/lesson-27-28-29-transition-to-react-redux-hooks-stackoverflow-0fsh6
Wish everyone get new taste in coding everyday.

Comment: It’s the Footer.  You’ve only exported it as a named export, not a default export.  You need to either export default Footer or change your import syntax to import { Footer } from "./components/Footer

Comment: hi,@LindaPaiste,I change following your road and the error run away,but one new pops out as-in `ReferenceError
FilterLink is not defined`

Comment: By the way I like your personal hub:www.lindapaiste.com

Comment: Thank you :)  FilterLink is a casing issue.  You've got both `Filterlink` (lowercase) and `FilterLink` (uppercase).  change `const Filterlink =` to `const FilterLink =`

Comment: thanks,another issue pop out?Need I reopen one question to reimburse your effort?In `Addtodo`component,`TypeError
(void 0) is undefined` and error direct to this line code `  this.input = node;
`

Comment: AddTodo is a function component so there is no “this”.  If you want to set a ref you can use a useRef() hook to create and store the ref, but that’s not the best way.  You want to use a controlled component instead, where the value of the input comes from state.  The React docs have lots of info on this: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components and https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html